# Find min values in field 2 by looping through certain number of records using AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gawk

I have three fields in dataset file.

field 1 acts as id

field 2 is used to compare the min

field 3 is boolean either 0 or 1.

I need to find the min value in field 2 but with respect to field 1.
that is, consider below dataset.

## dataset

```
1 0.432 0 
1 0.12  1
1 0.298 0
2 0.056 0
2 0.06  1
3 0.982 0
```

I need to compare the values in field 2 for first 3 records and check if field 3 has value = 1 for the min value in field 2. if so, ++count.

Then find min again in field 2 but for records with field 1 = 2. that is, only record 4 and 5.and so on...

What would be the best way to go about with it? The file contains approx 2,000,000 records.

Is it possible to sort field 2 and then take one record for each different value of field1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest...

```
$ sort -n file | awk '!a[$1]++'

1 0.12  1
2 0.056 0
3 0.982 0
```

to count the sum

```
$ sort -n file | awk '!a[$1]++{sum+=$3} END{print sum}'
1
```

however, if there is a match in field two and you want to pick the record with last field 1, you have to reverse sort for field 3, i.e. `sort -k1,2n -k3r`

**Explanation**

`!a[$1]++`  is an `awk` idiom to select the first unique entry for field 1.  Creating a counter mapped with key, logically will be true only for the first entry (due to negation and automatic conversion of values to boolean)

sorting: first two fields in ascending order (but numerical sort so 2 < 11), third is descending order (reverse) so that 1 will appear before 0.  Since last field is one digit only numerical sorting or lexical sorting doesn't matter, otherwise you want it to be numerical too.

Comment: Can you explain the code ' !a[$1]++ ' ? I dont get this part.

Comment: Also, please explain sort -k1 2n -k3r. I googled and it seems -k1 is the field that we are using to sort, -k3r is the field that we are sorting in reverse order. But could you explain? too many things are happening at once.

Comment: The best way to learn these is to test different flags on simple files.

Comment: Thank you so much, I needed this explanation to understand the working of it.